# Is it right for a ViewModel to inject itself into its child ViewModels?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, application-design

I created a [MVVM test application](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=213) which at runtime **reads an XML file to create a menu dynamically** and based on what the user selects, **loads in that page's UserControl dynamically**. The result is a nice MVVM pattern that allows you to have **one View/ViewModel pair per page** all defined in an XML file. Very nice.

So now I just added the ability for the developer to **create a button on one page that goes to another page**. The way I do this is in the MainViewModel I build the collection of ViewModels in the ObservableCollection and when I build each, I ***inject the MainViewModel itself* (this) into each UserControl-ViewModel's constructor**. This way each UserControl has inside of it the MainViewModel so that the developer can manipulate the application (e.g. call SwitchPage(idCode)) via the MainViewModel.

Also any **global state** that I need to save I can save in the MainViewModel to which each UserControl has access.

Also, each UserControl (PageItem) has **full access to each of the other UserControls** which gives me basically control of anything in the application from any UserControl, something that I have been trying to achieve in an MVVM application for a long time.

So my question is: **Is this kind of ViewModel injection a useful/known pattern or are there problems with injecting a ViewModel into its child ViewModels?** It seems recursive to me but seems to work fine and gives me the functionality I want so far. From what I have learned from the Composite Application Library architecture, this seems to be something similar that is going on there, and that e.g. in the code below I could inject other application objects into my ViewModels as they need them.

```
public MainViewModel()
{

    PageItems pageItems = PageItems.Create("all");

    foreach (PageItem pageItem in pageItems.Collection)
    {
        string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        string viewModelName = assemblyName + ".ViewModels.PageItem" + StringHelpers.ForcePascalNotation(pageItem.IdCode) + "ViewModel";
        var type = Type.GetType(viewModelName);
        var viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(type, this, pageItem) as ViewModelPageItemBase;
        AllPageItemViewModels.Add(viewModel);
    }

    CurrentPageItemViewModelIndex = 0;
    LoadCurrentPageItemViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't see this as wrong or right, but more about how coupled your design is. I normally start with the approach you mentioned (child VM references parent VM) and then decouple if I find it gets too unwieldy. Your first choice doesn't necessarily have to be your last - you can refactor your code as it evolves.

Possible alternatives are:

- child VM raises event that parent listens to (observer pattern). Parent VM knows children intimately, but child does not know parent.
- child VM publishes event on event hub that parent listens to (mediator pattern). Neither child nor parent are intimately aware of each other. They are aware only of the mediator.